# Search field for views

Tags: 7, search, views

How do I implement a search filter/field for my view? Lets say I have a view with a list of names/titles and there's a lot of them, so users could use search to filter through?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating a filter in a view you can expose the actual field to the use. 
In case of a title field you would create a filter for the field **Content: Title** and enable the checkbox *Expose this filter for visitors, to allow them change it*.

[Screenhot](http://share.undpaul.de/bilder/sr/20140529_113751.jpg)

After saving your view the filter would appear above your view. Depending on your search requirements you can also change the search-operator to several options. In case of a "Live search" on a big list of entries i would prefer to set the view to use *Ajax* in the *Advanced* settings of the view.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I did that, but after saving nothing appears. Also my view is a block not page.

Comment: Yep - i also tried to reproduce the problem with the block/ exposed filter. By turning on *Ajax* everything worked fine.